# Can't run a specific django project in a virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I need to edit but first run this project: https://pagure.io/fedora-commops/fedora-happiness-packets and it gives me errors even though I followed the instructions.

First I forked the repo, then cloned it to my computer and I followed the instructions listed in the setup section of the `README.md` file. When I run the command `./manage.py collectstatic` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/alexmarginean/Desktop/fed/fedora-happiness-packets/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Users/alexmarginean/Desktop/fed/fedora-happiness-packets/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/Users/alexmarginean/Desktop/fed/fedora-happiness-packets/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/alexmarginean/Desktop/fed/fedora-happiness-packets/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/alexmarginean/Desktop/fed/fedora-happiness-packets/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/Users/alexmarginean/Desktop/fed/fedora-happiness-packets/happinesspackets/messaging/models.py", line 15, in <module>
from happinesspackets.tasks import send_html_mail
  File "/Users/alexmarginean/Desktop/fed/fedora-happiness-packets/happinesspackets/tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
from happinesspackets._celery import app
  File "/Users/alexmarginean/Desktop/fed/fedora-happiness-packets/happinesspackets/_celery.py", line 2, in <module>
from celery import Celery
ImportError: No module named celery
```

I tried importing celery but that method didn't work and I don't want to mess with the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [issue 49](https://pagure.io/fedora-commops/fedora-happiness-packets/issue/49), it looks like `celery` is a dependency but it isn not listed in the requirements. Until that is fixed, you'll have to install it manually.

```
pip install celery
```

Comment: I tried this before but I think I typoed it. Because it was always giving me an error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you done pip install -r requirements in the virtualenv ?